# jquery find input:hidden error in safari

Tags: jquery, safari

I'm trying to implement a feature where a user can click on a row i.e., `<tr>`, and it'll go to a specific URL.

Here's my HTML and Jquery code:

```
                <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <input class="threadid_c" id="threadID" name="threadID" type="hidden" value="MzAwMTYwLDMwMDM3Miw=" />
                        <td>
                            ...
        </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <input class="threadid_c" id="threadID" name="threadID" type="hidden" value="MzAwMzcyLDMwMDM4MCw=" />
                        <td>
            ....

        $('#datatable tr').click(function() {
            var x = $(this).find("input:hidden");
            var url = "/User/Ping/" + x.val();
            location.href = url;
        });
```

This works fine in Chrome, Firefox, and IE. But in Safari, `x.val()` returns `undefined`.

I looked in Safari's JavaScript console, I see this message:

```
<input> is not allowed inside <tr>. Inserting <input> before the <table> instead.
```

Not sure if that's related to the problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a `<input>` as a direct `<tr>` child just like it says, just tuck it inside the first `<td>` instead, like this:

```
<tr>
   <td>
   <input class="threadid_c" name="threadID" type="hidden" value="MzAwMzcyLDMwMDM4MCw=" />
   ....
```

Also remove the `id` attribute since it's repeated...they should be unique in the page.